# Removing connection between two objects in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have been trying to remove the connection between the 2 and the 0 in the image below using erosion, but still can't manage to do it. Is there any other possible way of removing this connection between the two numbers?

[image: The image in question]

Comment: Can you not erode the image more than once or create a larger kernel for erosion?

Comment: If i do the numbers end up being split down the middles and some of them even dissapear and segmenting the numbers becomes even harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem using the morphological operations **erode** and **dilate**.

Some assumptions are required about the connection you want to remove.
I made the following assumptions:

- The connection area is the largest continuous region in the image.
- The width of the connected region is about 11 pixels.
- The shape of the connected region is tall and thin.

Here is a sample code:

```
I = imread('202.png'); %Read image.
I = rgb2gray(I); %Convert from RGB to grayscale.
I = imbinarize(I); %Convert to binary image.   

%Erode using large kernel - only the largest area in I is kept white.
Mask = imerode(I, ones(11)); %Result is the only the connection between 2 and the 0

%Expand the mask in the vertical direction
Mask = imdilate(Mask, ones(25, 1));

%Erase the connection by placing zeros.
I(Mask) = 0;

figure;imshow(I)
```

The above code:

- Builds a mask by eroding all the details, keeping only the connection rejoin.
- Expand the mask vertically.
- Erase the masked pixels in original image.

Mask result:
[image]

Final result:
[image]